# Most efficient way to parse a Comma Separated list in ApEx

Tags: oracle, csv, parsing, oracle-apex

I am still working on my first solo Oracle ApEx(Application Express) application, so I am sure that this will be old hat for some of you. I tried to look up what I want to do, but I am not sure what to even look up. If there is already a thread that answers this, then I apologize for duplication, but I have searched here for about two hours trying to figure this out.

I am open minded to a solution since I have not already built anything for this part of the application yet, so I am not locked into one set way. If there is a better way, please let me know.

I want to obtain a comma separated (or semi-colon, or colon separated) list from the user. I then want to take that data and write it to a table with each value in its own row.

Example of input:

```
X12345678, X22345678, X32345678 (and so on)
```

The numbers that are input will then be looked up on a different table because we use non-identifying PIDM numbers (Anyone that has used Ellucian's Banner will understand). This select statement is crazy simple to retrieve this number:

```
Select spriden_pidm 
from spriden 
where spriden_change_ind is null
  and spriden_id = :P5_STU_ID
```

Then, it will be stored in a table thusly:

Example of data storage:

```
   ID      |  Semester  |  Creating User  | Created Date | Data Origin
012345678  |   201640   |      JDOE1      |    sysdate   |  ApEx : 130
022345678  |   201640   |      JDOE1      |    sysdate   |  ApEx : 130
```

And so forth.

Question 1: I am presuming that a loop will be the best way to accomplish this using regular expressions. Would that be a correct presumption?

Question 2: Does ApEx already have something built in that would process this better and/or faster?

ApEx version 5.0, Oracle 12c

Answer (score 0):

[APEX_UTIL.string_to_table](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e12510/apex_util.htm#AEAPI185)

and use the comma for the second parameter

Comment: Thank you for this. Due to the time constraint, I was not able to use this method, although it appears to be exactly what I needed. We ended up writing our own loop that essentially accomplishes the same thing. Thank you, again.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, since we were working against the clock on a deployment, we ended up writing a loop similar to what the APEX_UTIL.string_to_table (Thanks Rob van Wijk) accomplishes:

```
declare

v_id varchar2(4000) := :P5_NEW_IDS;

begin

  for i in 1..regexp_count( v_id, ',' ) + 1 loop

  insert into zresadddrop.zsrintl(zsrintl_pidm,
                                zsrintl_term_code_eff,
                                zsrintl_created_by,
                                zsrintl_created_date,
                                zsrintl_data_origin)
  select distinct spriden_pidm
       , :P5_Term_Code
       , :app_user
       , sysdate
       , 'ApEx: '||:app_id

  from spriden

  where spriden_change_ind is null
    and spriden_id = trim(zgeneral.get_token(v_id,i));

end loop;
commit;

end;
```